# Is it possible to change the color of the notifications you get on PS4 after the new update?

Tags: ps4

After I updated my PS4 system to the newest version the color of the notifications changed from black to white. I think it's incredibly ugly and I was wondering if it's possible to change them back to black. I have already tried going into theme settings and system settings, but unfortunately I didn't find anything there

I think the version I updated my system to is 4.00.

Comment: I still don't understand why they changed it. I like the speed of the menu, but was it really necessary to change colors to something worse?

Answer (score 4):

As of version 5.00, the option to change the color of the notification box is now available. You can find this option by going to Settings > Notifications > Pop-up Color:

[image: settings > notifications]

[image: notifications > pop up color]

---

As of version 4.01, ***there is no way to change it***.

From [here](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Consoles-Peripherals/Notification-color-scheme-after-4-0/td-p/45955359):

> nope, no way to change it

And [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/52kd1u/is_there_a_way_to_change_the_notification_white/):

> The beta forums were filled with floods of people asking them to change it while also asking for adding a clock to the quick menu. Sad to see both went ignored and the community thing is still there looking as horrible as ever.

[Here](http://share.blog.us.playstation.com/ideas/2016/08/25/ability-to-change-notification-box-color/) is one of those petitions to have the ability added.

Answer (score 1):

Its the update that changed it and i also find it ugly and wishing i could change it unfortunately there is no current option to revert it yet hopefully sony will implement a toggle for this